# Can I rent a video using In-App Purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Can I use In-App Purchase to rent a song from a my webserver, play it once, then ask the user to pay for playing it again. My doubt comes from the developer guidelines, where it is stated in section 11.9 that:

> Apps containing "rental" content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected.

How long is a "limited time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limited time** means **any definite** amount of time.
If you say *You can rent this song for 1000 years*, the **limited time** is 1000 years.

Your app is likely to be rejected if you include this mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

The in-app purchase type **SUBSCRIPTION** this can be the solutions.

Subscriptions are one-time services that must be purchased again once the subscription period expires.

like
1. One-month subscriptions
2. Location service subscriptions

[Find more for the same over here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009)

This will be help full to you.

Comment: I don't think a subscription meets his needs--if it's a subscription, the user needs to have access to the content for as long as the paid subscription period. He wants to expire the content after a single use.

Comment: but then how to dynamically manage in app purchases for lets say 100 songs. it will be hard to create auto-renewing/non-renewing subscription for all the songs and most importantly it would be kind of static because if some song is added from the server after the release for which the corresponding itunes product id do not exist then wouldn't it will be a conflict?

Answer (score 1):

I think using consumable product in the in-app will do the trick.

Comment: I agree this sounds like consumable content, as long as they can listen to it whenever they want--you can't let them rent it, then expire the content after a day even if they didn't listen.

Comment: then how can you rent them?

Answer (score 0):

basically you can... according to all of the comments above i will give you a better idea that will not be rejected.
make your in app purchase as a auto-renwable purchase and provide a lot of movies to your subscribers.