# Floored by new rejection on non renewable subscription type in app purchases in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have an Iphone application in which i am trying to implement non renewable subscription.I had done it a manner that after the purchase i am adding that details to user account information.so he can get it on all the devices.I have a login at the start of my application.And after associating the reciept data with the user account i was finding out the expiry date in my server from the purchase date in the reciept data, by using that information i was showing the buy button again to my user.But the apple is rejecting it for the reasons

> 11.6: Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices
>
> 17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected

Can anybody know the exact mechanism to implement nonrenewable subscriptions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your description it sounds like your login when they start your app is **mandatory**.  Apple forbids this.  They insist that the login be **optional**, but it **must** still be available to everyone who wants to use it (when using non-renewing subscriptions).

What I did on my app was, next to where I show the user's purchased subscription level, I have a button that says `Save your account...`. And when they click it it describes to them how, if they create an e-mail and password than they can share their subscription across all their devices **and** they can restore their account if their iPhone gets lost or stolen.  You want to incentivize the user to do this because a better experience for them means a better experience for you.  You could even offer them a perk, like 2-weeks free if they create an account.  And since you're using non-renewing subscriptions, you have the power to do this since you're calculating your own expiration date, instead of letting the app store do it for you.

Comment: R u suggesting me to add a save your account button on my subscribed view?so what needs to be done at the begning of the app?

Comment: Yes. Add a save button to your subscribed view. As for the beginning of your app, find a way to not have a login. Or show a login window but make it clear that it's optional by providing a skip button or something.

Comment: Andrew, your answer really helps a lot.  One question, I want to make "Save your account" appears AFTER users purchased non-renewing subscription with 2-weeks free perk.

If users are asked to create an account while they are wondering if they should buy it, it could decrease the chance for them to purchase it.

Do you think Apple reject it if I don't show the option creating users account before they purchase non-renewing subscription?

Comment: @NonUmemoto I think it depends on the Apple reviewer you get. That sounds reasonable to me: after they purchase a subscription, the option to save the account appears.  It depends whether or not the reviewer does a test-purchase while evaluating the app. You could also put text on the signup page "You can save your account after purchase".  **Remember this though:** you have to give people the option to `Restore` their account *before* they purchase. For all you know, this user already signed up on their iPhone and now they're on the iPad and can't figure out how to sync their subscription.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  Restore means allowing users to log in to their account, not by restoreCompletedTransactions, since its non-renewable subs, am I right?

Comment: @NonUmemoto Yes, I should have been more clear. You're rolling your own account restore system here, since `restoreCompletedTransactions ` doesn't work with non-renewables.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Since "Save your account" is optional, what if the user doesn't save their account after purchasing non-renewable and they changed the device? How to restore to that device without having user details? What should we do in that case ? Could you clarify this one ? your above posts are really very helpful to understand the concept. Very Thanks