# Track non-renewing subscription with OAuth login?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Apple reject non-renewing subscription apps which doesn't provide user/password server side function to track the subscription.

I plan to implement Login and Signup Views with Parse.com.
https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

**I wonder if I can use Twitter or Facebook OAuth login to track the non-renewing subscription.**

**NOTE:**


The user can use my app without any registration at first, but when they want to upgrade to premium feature, they need to subscribe to non-renewing subscription.

So, I need to let users to register after they started using my app, not like usual SaaS apps. (ex, Evernote, DropBox, you need to log in or sign up before you start using their apps.)

I thought it would be easier if I can use OAuth login at the time.

**Related sources:**
[How to support multiple devices with non-renewing In-App Purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492898/how-to-support-multiple-devices-with-non-renewing-in-app-purchase?lq=1)
[app rejected.how to track user non-renewing subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466392/app-rejected-how-to-track-user-non-renewing-subscription)
[Monthly Subscription with IAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309917/monthly-subscription-with-iap?lq=1)
[Floored by new rejection on non renewable subscription type in app purchases in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862410/floored-by-new-rejection-on-non-renewable-subscription-type-in-app-purchases-in)

Comment: Don't they mean login to the user's iTunes/App Store account and from here check whether they are subscribed? Doesn't IAP support this so you can get the user's subscription and verify whether they are subscribed?

Comment: We need to implement login/password function based on own server if you use non-renewing-subs.  And, you are not allowed to use auto-renewable-subs for SaaS. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply from Apple through Resolution Center.

We can use OAuth to track a subscription after or before user buy it, but we need to permit user to buy a subscription without forcing user to log in to Twitter or Facebook OAuth.

This is the reply from apple.

> You may use Facebook or Twitter to track a subscription, however
>   logging in must be optional.