# iOS In App Purchase for expiring ecards

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an application that has a requirement for a user to be able to purchase an e-card. This is a digital image. The user is then permitted to share this e-card as many times as they wish within a 48 hour period (So, the card is visible in a 'My Cards' menu) It then disappears.

I'm looking through the apple documentation for IAP, and cant figure out if this should be a consumable, or a non-renewing subscription. I currently handle all the persistence and expiry myself within the app.

The problem with the latter is that it seems every card would need its own ProductID (Rather than me just having a product for 'A Card' and the app being aware of which one it is. There's over 200 cards so this doesn't seem feasible, but the methods one must implement don't seem to work like this. For example, a user may have 10 cards, all purchased at different times.

Does anyone know the correct type of purchase this should be, and the best way to implement it?

Comment: it is probably simplest to use a consumable purchase type. You can have a single product code and simply purchase this each time the user purchaes a card

Answer (score 0):

This answer [Floored by new rejection on non renewable subscription type in app purchases in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862410/floored-by-new-rejection-on-non-renewable-subscription-type-in-app-purchases-in?rq=1) , rather old (2012), claims that subscriptions must last for at least 7 days. Apart from that, iTunes Connect has no problem with 200 different products.

Comment: 11.6 Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices

Answer (score 0):

A non-renewing subscription might work but the 7 day issue is a problem for you.  A non-renewing subscription can be purchased many times so there is no problem with duplicate cards - as long as you keep track of that.

A consumable would work except a consumable can't 'expire in time' it can only 'expire when used'.  So if I purchase a card as a consumable I must be allowed to keep it on my device for a long time until I want to use it.  You could let the user do that - they keep the card but can't use it.  When they want to use it then it gets consumed and for the next 48 hours they can use it as often as they want.  You may need to explain to App Review that this is a consumable that does not expire but that can be used for a continuous 48 hour period once it finally gets consumed.

Comment: Ok so this consumable idea seems like it could work. By 'Using' it I mean, to share it. So it's not been used until its been shared, then allow it to be shared for 48 hours. So the actual consumable, is 48 hours of sharing.. Rather than the card its self. Makes sense. I think